# Inserting a comma before attributing a quote to a hypothetical speaker

Tags: commas

"Who cares why dealers love leases?," you say. "All I want is a low monthly payment."

Is there a comma required before attributing the quote here, or not?

Comment: The comma goes after the quote.

Comment: Many would insist that the comma is inappropriate, the question mark assuming dual duty.